# Moving rows by one in a 2d array in c?

Tags: arrays, c

Disclamer:Im a beginner.
So I had for my homework to write a program that moves rows, for example, row 0 to row 1,row1 to row 2, row 2 to row 0. A 3x3 matrix is in question. I wrote the code but it seems to not work, it shows numbers like -858993460. Here is my attempt(part of my code):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[10][10], n, m, i, j, k, l,transpose[10][10];
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter number of columns: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter elements of the matrix: ");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }

    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = a[i + 1][j];
                a[n - 1][n - 1] = a[0][0];
        }
        
    }
    printf("\n The new matrix is: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", a[i ][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }  ``
```

Comment: as int a[10][10] ,then later number of rows are entered which are 3

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be to have an array of pointers to int.

So you create an array of 3 pointers to int arrays of values

then just change what the pointers point to.

```
int * a[3]; // declares 3 pointers to arrays of int
```

now for each point allocate memory to hold the 3 int values

```
a[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
...

+------+     +--+--+--+
| a[0] | --> |  |  |  |
+------      +--+--+--+  
| a[1] | --> |  |  |  |
+------+     +--+--+--+
| a[2] | --> |  |  |  |
+------+     +--+--+--+
```

now you have three pointers to three allocated memory areas that can hold 3 int values.

to swap say a[1] with a[2] just do

```
int* tmp = a[1];
a[1] = a[2];
a[2] = tmp;
```

---

I see you have added some code since last I looked but there is still code missing. The reason for the weird values is that you are outside the matrix

```
for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
{
  a[i][j] = a[i + 1][j];
  a[n - 1][n - 1] = a[0][0];
}
```

Look carefully at `a[i+1][j]`  `i+1` in the last iteration of i, it will be outside the valid interval [0,n-1] and BTW what purpose has this:

```
a[n-1][n-1] = a[0][0];
```

assigning to the same location over and over again?

To copy one row to another row, have a temp storage to hold the previous content

```
int tmp;
```

say you want to swap row 1 and 2 in a 3x3 matrix

```
// I replaced "m" with the variable name "columns" 
// and "j" with "column" for clarity
int row1 = 1; 
int row2 = 2;

for (int column = 0; j < columns; ++column)
{
  int tmp = a[row1][column];
  a[row1][column] = a[row2][column];
  a[row2][column] = tmp;
}
```

You also need to read the row1 and row2 values from the user to
be able to know which rows to swap.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume n = 3, m = 3. When i = 2, j = 0; this line `a[i][j] = a[i + 1][j];` becomes `a[2][0] = a[3][0]`. 
In this case, a[3][0] is not initialized. ith index 0, 1, 2 is initialized not 3. Therefore, you are getting unexpected values.

Here is some modification to your last two nested loops to generate the expected output.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        transpose[i][j] = a[(i + 1)%n][j];
        //a[n - 1][n - 1] = a[0][0];
    }
    
}
printf("\n The new matrix is: \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", transpose[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying element by element use standard C functions which are optimized for your platform.

```
void moveRowDown(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    memmove(array[1], array[0], sizeof(*array) * (rows - 1));
    memset(array[0], 0, sizeof(*array));
}

void moveRowUp(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    memmove(array[0], array[1], sizeof(*array) * (rows - 1));
    memset(array[rows - 1], 0, sizeof(*array));
}
```

Those functions also zero  the row which is invalid after the move.